# what is the error_reporting number for php fatal errors only?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

I current have this set in my htaccess:

php_value error_reporting -1

I want the log to only log fatal errors. What do I replace -1 with to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/errorfunc.constants via https://www.google.de/search?q=php+error+constants

Comment: @KingCrunch I'm aware of that, but there is 1,16 and 64 that i want to log. How do I log all 3?

Comment: Are you aware of [the `error_reporting()` docs](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) as well? There _might_ be some examples there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always combine several flags with bit-operators.

```
echo E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR;
```

With `OR` it's easy: It's just `1 + 16 + 64 = 81`.

You can find examples on the manual page for [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/function.error-reporting) and about bit operators on the [manual page for bit operators](http://php.net/language.operators.bitwise).

As a sidenote: You cannot log `E_CORE_ERROR` or `E_COMPILE_ERROR` with PHP anyway, because they occur, *before* or *during* PHPs startup process.